# Why is this function returning nil? Is it because the D.S is lazy?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn get-doc-list [a-term]
     (map #(Integer/parseInt %)(take-nth 3 (take (* 3 3)(rest (rest a-term))))))
```

This function works well on small lists but returns an empty sequence on larger ones. What is the problem?

Comment: What does the symbol df represent in your function?  When I type your code in at the REPL it complains that df is undefined.

Comment: Sorry. df is just another function.  Replaced with an arbritrary term.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly an input issue, as your function will parse at most 3 integers:

```
user=> (get-doc-list (repeat "1"))
(1 1 1)
```

And only return empty sequence if less than 3 strings are supplied:

```
user=> (get-doc-list ["1" "1"])
()
```

And throw an exception if a non string is given:

```
user=> (get-doc-list [1 1 1])
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I suggest checking what the input it "fails" with really is... maybe you are passing in something like [["1" "1" "1" ...]]

```
user=> (get-doc-list [["1" "1" "1"]])
()
```

This is a vector of vectors, as you can see nothing is processed so there is no error or sequence to generate.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The issue is your use of the `take` function, which returns only the first n items of the collection.  Regardless of how big a collection you pass `get-doc-list`, only the first 9 get passed on to `take-nth`.</strike>

Comment: I think I've misread your question.  On running your code I find that I get a list of 3 parsed integers regardless of how big a list I pass in.  I wonder if the problem is your `df` method.  Would you mind including that with your question?

Comment: On reading the previous version of your question, I think seeing the definition of `df` would shed some light on the situation as `a-term` is passed in as an argument to that function as well.